# Error running script

Tags: firebird, ibexpert

I have a Firebird SQL script as follows :-

```
ALTER TABLE COSTCENT DROP ROW_VER;
ALTER TABLE COSTNUMB DROP ROW_VER;
```

When I run it in ibexpert, I get the following error :-

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, column 1.
ALTER.
```

why is this?

Why won't it run multiple statements, one after the other?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [IBExpert documentation](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SQLEditor):

> The SQL Editor is intended for the execution of single commands. The Script Executive should be used for more complex scripts.
>
> The Script Executive can be used to view, edit and execute SQL scripts. It can be started from the IBExpert Tools menu, using the respective icon in the Tools toolbar or [Ctrl + F12]. It is used for SQLs covering several rows. The Script Executive can both read and execute scripts.

Comment: Ah, forgot about the Script executive. Thank you.